# Filter Array and Remove Item if Undefined

Tags: arrays, node.js, array-filter

The array contains Items made up of a string and some variables. If one of the variables is undefined I would like to filter the whole item out of the Array. Example below.

Full Array:

```
[ 'hello', 'hi undefined', 'good day' ]
```

Filtered Array:

```
[ 'hello', 'good day' ]
```

Array Code:

```
  const testArray = [
            'hello',
            'hi ' + variableX, //variableX is undefined
            'good day'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string#includes` to check if a word exists in another word or sentence.

```js
const arr = [ 'hello', 'hi undefined', 'good day' ],
      result = arr.filter(word => !word.includes('undefined'));
console.log(result);
```